# Python 3: how to run NMAP commands through script

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, tls1.2, nmap

Nmap provides a TLS weak cipher detection library: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html which is run from the terminal through the command-

```
nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 <host>
```

My Python script needs to accommodate this `nmap` command, but couldn't find any resources on it.

**python-nmap**  package only works for open ports detection but not for SSL/TLS cipher suite scan.

I am unable to understand how to invoke **nmap ssl-enum-ciphers** command through a Python script.

Comment: you can try running a shell process as subroutine in python program.

Comment: I think this has all you need https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html